# React: Why does a class method render in development, yet it's "undefined" in production?

Tags: reactjs

I have a `class component`, on which, I have defined some `function components` as methods.

```js
export default class IssueBrowser extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { /* stuff */ }

  IssueList = (props) => {
    console.log("here"); // this never gets called
    if (this.state.issues.length > 0) {
       return (
          <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
            {this.state.issues.map(issue => 
               <this.IssueListItem key={issue.id} issue={issue} />
            )}
          </ul>
       )
    } else if (!this.state.noResponseFromServer) {
       return <div>There are no issues. Aren't you lucky?</div>
    } else {
       return null;
    }
 }

 {/* more stuff ... */}

 render() {
    return (
       {console.log(this.IssueList)}
       <this.IssueList />
    )
  }
}
```

If we focus within the `render()` method, here are some notes:

- `console.log()` shows the entire `this.IssueList` code so it appear that **it is defined**.
- In development, the `IssueList` actually renders (so it works).
- In production, `this.IssueList` appears to be `undefined`.

Questions:

- Do I really need to put `this.IssueList` somewhere else? Like say, outside of the main component?
- Also, a side question, what would `this.IssueList` be, technically speaking? A method on the `IssueBrowser` class?

This is the error in my production build:

```js
/*
// commented to avoid x-axis scroll...

Error: Minified React error #130; 
visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= 
for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors 
and additional helpful warnings.
...
From the link:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or 
a class function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
*/
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: class is just es6 syntax suger after transpilation its just Function and then this.IssueList is just property with function value

Comment: Why is it undefined only on a production build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`React Official docs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

> **Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.
>       React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags. For example,  represents an HTML div tag, but  represents a component and requires Welcome to be in scope**

`this.IssueList` definitely pointing to `IssueList`.But it render as DOM tags as name start with lowercase which does not exist.

```
It should be     <IssueList /> and not <this.IssueList/>.
```

Development mode always run in non-strict mode.Thats why it worked there.But production always run in Strict mode. So, it will not work.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll re-factor and see if that changes anything. This is working in my development environment though... it seems super convenient to be able to just do `<this.MyComponent />`, is there a workaround? Or do I have to move `<this.IssueList />` outside of my component? In my development environment, I can do `<this.IssueList />` and not have to pass a bunch of state via props, which is why I wanted to do it that way initially.

Comment: I think, you should define  separate component IssueList and IssueListItem outside class to make a code more DRY.